# How to use regex in bash while loop to modify csv data per line?

Tags: regex, bash, csv, unix

I have a csv file and need to extract number values from 1 column for all rows. How do i go about doing this? 
I have the regex to extract the values but unsure how to apply it for all rows in csv files with 1000+ records.

```
 1. CREATE_DATE  |  NAME      |  PROD_ID
 2. 12/01/2018 | starburst 25g | 2323
 3. 01/23/2018 | 43g hersheys  | 4353
```

expected result:

```
 1. 25
 2. 43
```

Comment: If you have no idea where to start, try reading [the GNU `sed` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command) to parse this: `sed -En '2,${ s/^[^|]+[|][^0-9|]*([0-9]+).*$/\1/; p;}' infile` - Once you have an attempt, and can show what it's doing wrong, we can discuss how to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

using a combination of awk and sed you can strip out everything from the csv expect for the digits.

awk -F allows you to change the delimeter from the default space to another special character so in your case a pipe "|" therefore the results of this command will just be startburst 25g then the sed command will only display the int values from that line, so 25.

EDIT just saw the title, that this will be in a loop so you can read the line from the loop and modify each line

```
while read line ; do
    echo  $line | awk -F  "|" '/1/ {print $2}' | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'
done < filename.csv
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to spawn external commands for each line of the input file.
You are repeatedly creating and exiting child processes of `awk` and `sed`
thousands of times, which is a big overhead.
Why don't you do it just with a `sed` or `awk`?

Comment: @tshiono I wrote it up like this since the OP asked how to accomplish this in a loop. Yes you could just sed or awk and entire output but I dont believe that is what they were looking for